# search result from sql error with codeigniter's pagination index

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

I have a table with the `pagination`. First, i select all data from my DB, and the `pagination` works perfectly.

Then, i started to **filter the data** (search certain data, example : using `WHERE` in SQL). The pagination's 1st index is working perfectly (showing only certain data) but when i click the **next index** (2nd, 3rd) the data is going back to default (the **filter** (`WHERE`, `LIKE`) is **not** working).

This is my `model` that used for the pagination (**I think i made a mistake here**) :

```
public function get_umat() {
        $this->db->select('*')->from('msumat')->limit(10, $this->uri->segment(3));
        $this->db->join('mskelas', 'msumat.kelas_id = mskelas.kelas_id');

        $search = $this->input->post('ddl_search');
        $kelas = $this->input->post('ddl_kelas');
        $kelas1 = $this->input->post('ddl_kelas1');
        $kelas2 = $this->input->post('ddl_kelas2');
        $nama = $this->input->post('txt_nama');
        $alamat = $this->input->post('txt_alamat');
        $bulan = $this->input->post('ddl_bulan');
        $bulan1 = $this->input->post('ddl_bulan1');
        $bulan2 = $this->input->post('ddl_bulan2');

        if($this->input->post('btn_search')) 
        {
            if($search === 'nama')
                $this->db->like('nama', $nama);

            else if($search === 'kelas')
                $this->db->where('mskelas.kelas_id', $kelas);

            else if($search === 'range_kelas')
                $this->db->where("mskelas.kelas_id BETWEEN $kelas1 AND $kelas2");

            else if($search === 'alamat')
                $this->db->like('alamat', $alamat);

            else if($search === 'bulan_lahir')
                $this->db->where("MONTH(tanggal_lahir) = $bulan");

            else if($search === 'range_tanggal_lahir')
                $this->db->where("MONTH(tanggal_lahir) BETWEEN $bulan1 AND $bulan2");
        }

        return $this->db->get()->result();
    }

public function count_umat(){
        return $this->db->count_all('msumat');
    }
```

Then this is my `pagination` in `controller` (I think i need to modify the `$config['total_rows']`):

```
$config['base_url'] = site_url('/backend_umat/index');
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->umat_m->count_umat();
        $config['per_page'] = 10; 
        $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
        $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div id="pagination">';
        $config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';

        $this->pagination->initialize($config); 

        $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
```

I think the problems are :

1. I need to `COUNT` the search results (for each search) for `$config['total_rows']`
2. Somehow, i need to modify the `model` (`get_umat()`) to get things working

Any help is appreciated. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

well in CI if you want to apply search with multiple filters it works for the first page and ci always look for url segments, for 2nd or 3rd page you need to send your all search parameters which you send for the first page through form, means you url should contain url segments then you can filter your search record because you are not submitting form for 2nd and 3rd page. i will suggest you to have look on this tutorial it has nice way to use search records with multiple filters and work perfect with pagination

[CI Search on Tutorial Nettuts](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/codeigniter-from-scratch-search-results-without-query-strings-2/)

Comment: Thanks for your help :D I'm watching now. I will accept your answer if  it can fix my problem. Too bad, i only can upvote once :D

Comment: no problem well this solution is best for search and filtering record from database i have used the same on this project too http://www.uaeboattrading.com/

Comment: I think the conclusion of this video is we need to use something like "querystring" to make the search working. Is it true?im still on my way :D

Comment: yes query string will be saved in database and it will generate and id of that saved query string to which you can use for paginiation and every possible combinations of search terms will be save in database

Comment: Okay, thanks for the tuts. I will let you know after i finished implement this tuts

Comment: Hello, i keep getting this error : 
Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_Input::load_query() in C:\xampp\htdocs\ci_gabdb\application\controllers\backend_umat.php on line 38 Do you have any idea?i have followed the tutorial (but not the exact code). Thanks

Comment: I have downloaded the source code to make sure my custom library (MY_Input) dont have any mistake/typo. However, i still get the fatal error.

Comment: where you have put MY_Input file, you have to put MY_Input file in application core directory of your project